# Android - sign XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, digital-signature

I am creating an android application that is creating XML files, which need to be signed using .p12 certificates private key. In JDK that is trivial to do, but i am unable to find any good examples of how to do that on android, since javax cannot be used. How can XML data/files be signed on Android?

Any examples/pointers are much appreciated.